# ListView: how do I wait until it's loaded up?

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a ListView with an ArrayAdapter, and code executing after `ListView.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter,...)` is seeing `ListView.getChildCount()==0`.

Is there a way t wait for the UI thread to finish filling the ListView before continuing?

Thanks in advance,
Lenny

Answer (score 1):

ListView.getChildCount() is inherited from ViewGroup and is not related to the items managed by the adapter but the child views managed by the ListView. 
To get the number of items displayed by the ListView use getCount() which returns the number of items managed by the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I solved creating a thread that has while loops that can only go forward after the list is loaded.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
       while(listView.getCount() == 0) ;
    } 
}).start();
```

This approach can be done cuz I garantee that at this point there is something in the list. Be carefull using this approach. It is not the best one but it was the one that I found.